# Allow users to make changes to sharpoint items, but not edit the fields behind these

Tags: list, sharepoint, permissions

We use SharePoint to allow users to request changes that could be made to our system. When adding a new item to a list, there are certain fields they are required to fill in. We want this behaviour to remain. One of these fields is Release Phase, where we have a list of release phases they can select from. We still want them to be able to select a release phase, however recently the release phase names have been changing and we want to stop users having access to the list settings so they are unable to edit the options shown.

We still want them to be able to contribute to items, just not edit some of the selectable fields we have.

Any ideas of what can be done to stop this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trying to clarify - the users are accessing the list settings and changing the choices for the Release Phase column?

Comment: Yes, they must be changing it through list settings as its the only way I can see it happening. We only want certain people or a group to change the choices in list settings, but all users should have the ability to select a choice that is available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure custom permissions on your list to ensure that only a set few people have access to edit the list, but others can edit the items in the list.

If you are fine with users being able to delete these items, you can set their permission to **Contribute** which will allow them to add, update, and edit list items, but they will not have any permissions to manage the lists themselves.

If you want to avoid deleting items as well, you need to create a new permission level.

So, there are steps to solve your problem.

1.) Break inheritance on the list to give it unique permissions and apply the appropriate permissions.
2.)Create a new permission level to ensure users only have the level of permission that you want for the list.

1.) Navigate to the list settings for the list in question. Choose "Permissions for this list." You should see a button in the top ribbon that says "Stop inheriting Permissions". [image]

Once you have broken inheritance, this list will no longer be affected by permission changes to its parent site. Only the permissions you define on the list will have affect. Select all the permissions that were defined before, and delete them, so that you will have a clean slate to start with.

You can then grant permissions to the specific users/groups you want. If you have a large base of users, you will find it easier to manage and control permissions by groups.

2.) To define a custom permission level, you need to navigate to the parent site that the list belongs to and go the Site Permissions. This will give you the ability to create new permission groups, and permission levels. There is a ribbon option for each. Select permission levels.

Have a look at each of the predefined options, and see if those will suit your needs first. You can click on each permission level to drill down and see all the specific permissions that it gives. If none of the predefined options work, then Add a new Permission Level, and assign the permissions as needed. Then go back to step 1, and assign your users/groups to your newly created permission level.

Ensure that this option is deselected to prevent users from editing list settings [image]